# KIVY: How to multitask

Tags: python, kivy, multitasking

I want to display a loading animation in kivy while something else is being done. How can I do that? I'm sorry I have no sample code, I just have no idea where to start.

Comment: It's difficult to comment without seeing the code. But generally you can use threading to do some tasks which doesn't update the GUI. In that way while the loading animation is ongoing some other tasks will be performed in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, and you can use a thread to make this happen.

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but let's say you want to load something when you click a button. While loading you want to display a popup saying "loading". Here is a simple example program that would let you do this.

**main.py**

```
import threading
import time

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class ExampleApp(App):
    def show_popup(self):
        # Create and open a popup
        self.loading_pop = Popup(title='Please wait', 
                                 content=Label(text='Loading...'),
                                 size_hint=(.8, .5), auto_dismiss=False)
        self.loading_pop.open()

    def process_btn_click(self):
        self.show_popup() # Open the popup

        # Start a thread, this allows you to display the popup while
        #     running some long task
        my_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.some_long_task)
        my_thread.start()

    def some_long_task(self):
        current_time = time.time()
        while current_time + 3 > time.time():  # 3 seconds
            time.sleep(1)

        # When the task is done, let the popup display "Done!"
        self.loading_pop.content.text = 'Done!'
        # Also let the user click out of the popup now
        self.loading_pop.auto_dismiss = True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ExampleApp().run()
```

**example.kv**

```
Screen:
    Button:
        text: 'Click me'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        size_hint: .3, .2
        on_release:
            app.process_btn_click()
```

Hope this answered your question!